# Strip Not Removing Tabs

Tags: python, python-3.x

My understanding is `strip():` returns a new string after removing any leading and trailing whitespaces including tabs (\t).

I have source text of several lines. One line starts with what appears to be a tab leading the "B" character

> Bean Drop Temperature   332

Why doesn't the following Python 3 code recognize this as a line starting with "Bean"?

```
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    # strip beginning and ending whitespace from lines
    line.strip()
    if line.startswith('Bean') :
        count = count + 1
print("There were", count, "lines in the file with Bean as the first word")
```

If I change one line to include a couple spaces, then it works.

```
    if line.startswith('  Bean') :
```

Comment: "My understanding is strip(): **returns a new string**". It doesn't modify the original.

Comment: OK. So they failed to mention that in the class I took. Seems like they've been publishing a bad example. That line has been pervasive. Thank you.

Comment: @DenVog. I'm amazed by how often stuff like that gets through the cracks. The most valuable skill in the information age is filtering information, not so much finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears Carcigenicate got it. If I modify the line to be:

```
line = line.strip()
```

This solves it. Doh!

Comment: Or `if line.strip().startswith('Bean'):`

Answer (score 1):

An important mantra to repeat to yourself.  Strings are immutable.  Strings are immutable.  Strings are immutable. No function will ever change the value of a string.  It will create a new string.

If you do something like:

```
x = "abc"
y = x
x += "d"
```

The value of `y` will still be `"abc"`.  Python creates a new string to assign to `x` while `y` still has the old string.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you figured it out! But for people who need a bit more context:

As Frank said, strings are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed once created. The `.strip()` method returns a new string. It does **not** change the original string.
So if we take another look at the code:

```
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    # strip beginning and ending whitespace from lines
    line.strip()
    if line.startswith('Bean') :
        count = count + 1
```

We can see that the issue with the code is that you're not storing the new string that's created by `line.split()` so the `if` statement that comes after it is still using the old string (the one that has the whitespace). 
That's why it suddenly works when you change the `line.startswith("Bean")` to `line.startswith("   Bean")`.

The fix is to just assign the new stripped string to the old string variable, essentially replacing the old string with the new one:

```
line = line.strip()
```

---

More on `.strip()` method: [Python Documentation - str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)
More on strings in general: [Python Documentation - Text Sequence Type (str)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str)